# How to Debug.Print multiple variables?

Tags: c#, parameters

Right now, I'm doing this.

```
Debug.Print(varA.ToString());
Debug.Print(varB.ToString());
Debug.Print(varC.ToString());
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
Debug.Print(varA, varB, varC);
```

I could do something like that in VB but not C#.

The MS docs show this example

```
public static void Print (string format, params object[] args);
```

which I (apparently incorrectly) interpreted to mean something like

```
Print("D", {VarA, VarB, VarC});
```

but nope, that's not it.

Comment: If *'that's not it.'* then what is 'it' ? What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: @Fabjan Is the title of the question really not clear? Someone else had no problem and answered it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It is not clear enough. For example there is no way of telling whether you always have only 3 parameters or you're looking for a solution for *N* parameters in which case some answers might not be as accurate as they are

Comment: @Fabjan The answer below instructs to do this `Debug.Print($"{VarA} {VarB} {VarC}");` It would seem that works for N parameters. But I hear what you're saying. I will try to be more clear in the future. By the same token, consider sometimes just answering the question. The inquirer is often already confused enough as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format string should be like this:

```
"{0} {1} {2}"
```

The numbers indicate where the rest of the arguments in the printed string.

And you don't need `{}` around the rest of the arguments (note the `params` modifier in the parameter declaration):

```
Debug.Print("{0} {1} {2}", VarA, VarB, VarC);
```

After C# 6, you don't need to use format strings anyway, because interpolated string literals got introduced:

```
Debug.Print($"{VarA} {VarB} {VarC}");
```